# Simplest way to display a window with dots on it

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe

I have spent the last hour perusing the internet on how exactly to create a super simple display in my program. Here is the situation:

1.) I have a for loop that runs an arbitrary number of times. Each iteration, it spawns a "city", that is, a randomly generated x coordinate and y coordinate (both ints).

2.) I want to create the SIMPLEST display possible. Nothing fancy. That is, ideally, a window, sized 600x600, that draws a single black dot for each city for each iteration of this for loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for (int i = 0; i <= nodeArray.length-1; i++)
    {
        nodeArray[i] = new Node();
        nodeArray[i].x = 0 + (600 - 0) * r.nextDouble();
        nodeArray[i].y = 0 + (600 - 0) * r.nextDouble();

        //DRAW DOT HERE?
    }
```

For each iteration of this for-loop, I want to draw, in this window, a black dot with x coordinate (int)nodeArray[i].x and y coordinate (int)nodeArray[i].y

I REALLY appreciate any help. This is a somewhat high-level algorithms course, and I'm kind of embarrassed I can't seem to figure out how graphics actually work in Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve, but basically, you need some way to paint the result to the screen.

If the data doesn't change often, it's best to use a backing buffer as it is faster to renderer rather then having to loop through the data set each time.

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

**Animated**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Dotty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dotty();
    }

    public Dotty() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int count = 0;
        private int dotCount = 1000;
        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {
            background = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Timer timer;
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    if (count < dotCount) {
                        int x = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 600));
                        int y = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 600));
                        Graphics2D g2d = background.createGraphics();
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2d.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                        g2d.dispose();
                        repaint();
                    } else {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Straight render**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Dotty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dotty();
    }

    public Dotty() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int count = 0;
        private int dotCount = 1000;
        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {
            background = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            for (int count = 0; count < dotCount; count++) {
                int x = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 600));
                int y = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 600));
                Graphics2D g2d = background.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                g2d.dispose();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```